# How do I use zsh to pipe results from one command to another (while in a loop)?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, zsh

```
macOS 10.14.6
zsh 5.8
jq 1.6
```

I have a situation where I have a bunch of `.vital` files, which are JSON files in disguise. I want to extract one piece of information from each file, and I have worked out that after installing jq using `brew install jq`, I can run, for example...

```
jq '.author' Analog_Bass__Lead.vital;
```

This gives me...

```
"maniclout"
```

which is the correct author for that item.

What I would like to do is to run this command over all my `.vital` files, about 30 of them, in a `for` loop.

I can list the files okay using...

```
for f in $(ls *.vital);
do
  echo $f
done;
```

The problem comes when I try to construct  a loop that would give the following...

```
Analog_Bass__Lead.vital "maniclout"
Blackhole_Dimension.vital "Cobranix"
```

and so on...

This my latest attempt (please, don't laugh!)...

```
for f in $(ls *.vital);
do
  echo $f;
  echo -n $f | jq ‘.author’
done;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to print the filename, followed by, on the same line, hence the `-n`, and I'm trying to pipe the filename into the `jq` command.

The results are fairly disastrous!

```
ANALOG_PAD_-_6.vital
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
‘.author’
jq: 1 compile error
Analog_Bass__Lead.vital
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
‘.author’
jq: 1 compile error
Atomosphere_Lead.vital
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
‘.author’
jq: 1 compile error
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

Do *not* [parse/interpret the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs),  too many things can go wrong. A simple way to accomplish your goal would be

```bsh
for f in *.vital; do
    echo -n "$f: "
    jq '.author' "$f"
done
```

which might still fail if there are directories matching the pattern for instance. You can overcome this by using

```bsh
for f in *.vital; do
    [[ -f "$f" ]] || continue
    echo -n "$f: "
    jq '.author' "$f"
done
```

You can also go the full way and run

```bsh
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.vital' \
     -exec sh -c 'echo -n "$1"; jq ".author" "$1"' _ {} \;
```

(see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Complex_actions for how this works)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116670/discussion-on-answer-by-nohillside-how-do-i-use-zsh-to-pipe-results-from-one-com).

Answer (score 1):

You could use find to get a list of `.vital` files and then pipe that to `jq`:

```
find *.vital | xargs jq '.author'
```